# Not Found: /users/

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql, django

I keep getting this error even though I have pathed it correctly. Can someone help me? Thanks.

this is my form action url

> form method="post" action="/users/" id="archive-form"

this is my javascript fetch url

> fetch("/users/", {

this is my urls.py path url

> path("users/", views.users, name="users"),

this is my views.py

```
def users(request):
active_users = User.objects.filter(status='active')
archive_users = User.objects.filter(status='archived')
user_form = UserForm()

if request.method == 'POST':

    user_form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        user.save()
        # log_message = f"Added user with ID {user.id}"
        Log.objects.create(user=user.first_name, role=user.job_title, date=timezone.now(), action=log_message)
    # return redirect('app:users')

    print('1')
    user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
    if user:
        if user.status == 'active':
            user.status = 'archived'
            log_message = f"Archived user with ID {user_id}"
        elif user.status == 'archived':
            user.status = 'active'
            log_message = f"Unarchived user with ID {user_id}"
        user.save()
        Log.objects.create(user=user.first_name, role=user.job_title, date=timezone.now(), action=log_message)

    return redirect('app:users')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use a relative path like this:

`form method="post" action="./users/" id="archive-form"`

Absolute paths start with `/`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't appear to be working...

Answer (score 0):

Only indentation can defines the scope of function. In your code snippet indentation level is not correct for function `users`.

Try to check and fix your indentation level in `users` function in `views.py` file.

```
def users(request):
    active_users = User.objects.filter(status='active')
    archive_users = User.objects.filter(status='archived')
    user_form = UserForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
            # log_message = f"Added user with ID {user.id}"
            Log.objects.create(user=user.first_name, role=user.job_title, date=timezone.now(), action=log_message)
        # return redirect('app:users')

        print('1')
        user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
        if user:
            if user.status == 'active':
                user.status = 'archived'
                log_message = f"Archived user with ID {user_id}"
            elif user.status == 'archived':
                user.status = 'active'
                log_message = f"Unarchived user with ID {user_id}"
            user.save()
            Log.objects.create(user=user.first_name, role=user.job_title, date=timezone.now(), action=log_message)

        return redirect('app:users')
```

Comment: Sorry, in my code there is indentation, just can't seem to press tab here to fix it.

Comment: @JR you can click SPACE four times

Comment: Can try removing the: action="/users/" in the form.